# How to download a file from URL using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm writing a docker file to install a certain library. The first step it does is download the library from a URL. I'm not sure if it's possible in docker.

I need to install the library on RedHat System.
http://service.sap.com/download  is the URL I need to download the library. How can I write Dockerfile for the same?

Comment: A Dockerfile is (largely) just a collection of shell commands. How would you do this without a Dockerfile?

Comment: You can simply use "RUN wget  http://service.sap.com/download" to download the library

Comment: This is also something Docker can do on its own if you [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) the URL.

Comment: Thanks so much guys for your reply and sharing information.

Comment: Using wget has one benefit: ADD downloads file each time you making `docker build`. If it is a big file(s) - built can take a long time (and bandwith) every time. `RUN wget` will download only once and use docker cache afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), as [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) commented and as [@nicobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579827/nicobo) commented on the first answer.

I think that this is the best answer for many of us, since it does not force download of `wget` or similar into the Docker image.  Here is the example I just used for CMake:

```
ADD https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.27.6/cmake-3.27.6-linux-x86_64.sh /tmp/cmake.sh

RUN mkdir /opt/cmake && bash /tmp/cmake.sh --prefix=/opt/cmake --skip-license && rm /tmp/cmake.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You run a RUN command depending on the programs available in your system. If you have wget on your system, you just put the command in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN wget http://your.destination/file
```

If you need that file to move to a location in your image, you keep using the `RUN` command with `mv`, if the file is outside your image, you can use the `COPY` command.

To resume, downloading your file from the system

```
[CLI] wget http://your.destination/file
[DOCKERFILE] COPY file .
```

Downloading a file with docker

```
[DOCKERFILE] RUN wget http://your.destination/file
[DOCKERFILE] RUN mv file my/destination/folder
```

Comment: Thanks @savageGoat for your answer.

Comment: See David Maze comment above : ADD is a Dockerfile instruction to do exactly that ; although RUN wget is possible, it needs first to have wget installed inside the image.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add